# How do I import a Blend file from another project without losing its materials,shapekeys in the imported version etc.

Tags: import, blend-files, append

I download an eye from blendswap and tried to append it to another project but lost all the information on it except the mesh itself. What i really want is a way to import the model with its textures once so i don't have to separately import the textures re-texture the eye.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you've appended a mesh, which relates to vertices edges and faces only.

If you append an object instead, you will have all the textures and others attributes.

If your object is maden of different spare parts, select all objects you need (meshes, armatures, texts, curves, ....) make a group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>) and append the whole group.